# Retrieving data from a relational database

Tags: java, android, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have set up 2 two tables - table userid and table data in phpmyadmin. The userid table consists of a single column - id and the table data consists of the following columns- `id|name|price`. I have added an index in the column id of table userid to point to id of the table data. Now i have a user who makes certain selections inside an android application. I want to insert this data into the table data. I know i have to use jdbc and know how to enter data for table without any index. But i am confused as to how to go about doing it in the case of related tables. The userid is obtained from this link http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html. Would someone please tell me how to enter the data using java. (The confusion is how to enter the userid and the corresponding data ).

Comment: When you say that you have added an index in the column id of table userid to point to id of the table data, do you mean that `data`.`id` is the foreign key for `userid`.`id`? If so is it, then it is not possible to insert into `data` without having a corresponding record in `userid`. Or have I not understood your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're aware of the user id when you're inserting a new record into the data table that's all you need. Basically you'll have:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate( "INSERT INTO data (id, name, price) VALUES ('id from userid table', 'a name', 'a price')");
```

Obviously the params aren't escaped properly (they really should be) and there's no testing for errors, but that would get you started.

Then to, for example, select all the data related to a given userid, you would do something like:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM userid LEFT JOIN data WHERE userid.id = data.id" );
```

Comment: I thought indexing tables would increase the speed and reduce repetions.Or am i mistaken here.

Comment: @user1092042 Absolutely, but what you were asking about can be handled by adding an index on the id field in the user table, the index doesn't need to be stored in a separate table.

Comment: But the data needs to be identified right. If i have many users then i need to know which data belongs to whom. Sorry if i am seeming stupid but i am pretty new.(The index is being stored in the data table as a foreign key )

Comment: Updated my answer as I think I misunderstood your question originally.

Comment: Yes. I think thats what i am looking for. But just one more thing. The user id is a relatively long id and consists of a 16 character long string. assuming that a single user has more than one record of data to enter i would have to repeat the id in the column id of table data. Is there any way to get over this as the current situation would cause my table data to grow extremely big due to the repetition of the same userid for multiple names and price.

Comment: @user1092042 You could abstract it into another table and use the auto_incremented id. However, 16 characters is not a whole lot and unless you have a truly huge amount of data it's not going to be a significant bottleneck for you. Consider that if you set that field appropriately to varchar(16) you'll be using 17 bytes per field (per  MySQL docs). That means even with a million records we're still only talking 17MB for your ids.  Also, please accept my answer if you thought it was helpful.

Comment: Completely forgot about accepting your answer. Sorry about that.